Unable to update to Laravel 11 due to symfony/process "missing" dependency
I am attempting to update a large Laravel app to Laravel 11 (i.e. turning it up to 11 :-)), and when I update the version of laravel/framework in composer.json, and run composer update laravel/framework I get this:
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies                                 
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^11.0, found laravel/framework[v11.0.0, ..., 11.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/octane is locked to version v1.5.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laravel/octane v1.5.6 requires laravel/framework ^8.83.26|^9.38.0|^10.0 -> found laravel/framework[v8.83.26, v8.83.27, 8.x-dev, v9.38.0, ..., 9.x-dev, v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^11.0).

so when I run composer update (after updating versions of laravel/framework, laravel/octane, and symfony/http-kernel in composer.json)
composer update laravel/octane symfony/process laravel/framework illuminate/support symfony/http-kernel -W

I get
  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v11.0.0, ..., 11.x-dev] require symfony/process ^7.0 -> found symfony/process[v7.0.0-BETA1, ..., 7.2.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^11.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v11.0.0, ..., 11.x-dev].

However, if I try to figure out conflicts for symfony/process
composer why-not symfony/process ^7

I get
No dependencies installed. Try running composer install or update, or use --locked.

even though I count 14 references to symfony/process in composer.lock
How can I get past this to get everything updated?
UPDATE:
So I've been going down a different route of specifically listing packages in the composer update command as I get the message Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
Running composer show illuminate/support shows that up to 11.10.0 is available.  I ran composer why-not ^11 and 1) updated every package listed to one that supports illuminate/support ^11 and 2 )added those to my composer update list.
composer update laravel/framework laravel/process laravel/octane illuminate/support symfony/http-kernel govtribe/framework sebastian/diff phpstan/phpdoc-parser giggsey/locale symfony/console nunomaduro/termwind laravel/prompts symfony/process laravel/horizon php-webdriver/webdriver staudenmeir/dusk-updater symfony/panther sentry/sentry-laravel govtribe/agency-images govtribe/framework barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper illuminate/filesystem nunomaduro/collision cartalyst/stripe-billing-laravel cartalyst/stripe-laravel laravel/dusk laravel/sanctum spatie/laravel-sitemap beyondcode/laravel-dump-server phpunit/phpunit propaganistas/laravel-phone stevebauman/purify sentry/sentry-laravel -W

In doing so, I get my errors down to this:
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^11.0, found laravel/framework[v11.0.0, ..., v11.10.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^11.0, found phpunit/phpunit[11.0.0, ..., 11.1.3] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 3
    - Root composer.json requires govtribe/agency-images dev-master as 1.0 -> satisfiable by govtribe/agency-images[dev-master].
    - govtribe/agency-images dev-master requires illuminate/support ^11.0 -> found illuminate/support[v11.0.0, ..., v11.10.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 4
    - Root composer.json requires govtribe/framework dev-feature/675-update-laravel-11 -> satisfiable by govtribe/framework[dev-feature/675-update-laravel-11].
    - govtribe/framework dev-feature/675-update-laravel-11 requires illuminate/support ^11.0 -> found illuminate/support[v11.0.0, ..., v11.10.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 5
    - previousnext/phpunit-finder is locked to version 2.0.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - previousnext/phpunit-finder 2.0.2 requires phpunit/phpunit ^9.5 -> found phpunit/phpunit[9.5.0, ..., 9.6.19] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^11.0).
  Problem 6
    - cartalyst/stripe-laravel v16.0.0 requires illuminate/support ^11.0 -> found illuminate/support[v11.0.0, ..., v11.10.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - cartalyst/stripe-billing-laravel dev-mongodb_11_laravel_11_compat requires cartalyst/stripe-laravel ^16.0 -> satisfiable by cartalyst/stripe-laravel[v16.0.0].
    - Root composer.json requires cartalyst/stripe-billing-laravel dev-mongodb_11_laravel_11_compat -> satisfiable by cartalyst/stripe-billing-laravel[dev-mongodb_11_laravel_11_compat].


We don't use previousnext/phpunit-finder any more, so I want to remove it, but when I do composer remove previousnext/phpunit-finer -W, I get basically the same errors. IfI just run composer update -W, I just get
  Problem 1
    - previousnext/phpunit-finder[2.0.0, ..., 2.0.2] require phpunit/phpunit ^9.5 -> found phpunit/phpunit[9.5.0, ..., 9.6.19] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^11.0).
    - Root composer.json requires previousnext/phpunit-finder ^2.0 -> satisfiable by previousnext/phpunit-finder[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].

so that one seems to be the hangup. Any suggestions on how I can get around it?

composer update laravel/framework -W

Would the Upgrade Guides be of any use here?

Use laravel/octane ^2.3

laravel/octane v1.5.6 requires laravel/framework ^8.83.26|^9.38.0|^10.0  - anything unclear about this? Which version of Octane did you update to?

previousnext/phpunit-finder 2.0.2 requires phpunit/phpunit ^9.5 - if you require PHPUnit v11 and want to install any other pacakge that requires v9.5, it's obvious that Composer can't resolve this for you
